# How to fit the page into landscape while print

Tags: javascript, html, css, landscape

I need to print a page, while giving to print it is splitting to two pages. The page is splitting after the second table, is there any way to fit it to one page.

[image]

I am providing the code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>View JTC</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css" media="print">
@media print {
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    table {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    @page {
        size: A4 landscape;
    }
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <section class="container-fluid">

        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-condensed">

            <tr>
                <th style="width: 30%; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;">logo</th>
                <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center; width: 70%">company</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th rowspan="2" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">Job
                    Travel Card</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;">JTC No:</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-sm  table-bordered table-condensed">

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 10%; text-align: left;">Project Number</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;" colspan="2"></td>
                <td style="width: 10%; text-align: left;">Unit No. / Tag No.</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;" colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Area Number</td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
                <td>Material Class</td>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;">Drawing No: / ISO
                    Number</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;"></td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;">JC No:</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;"></td>

                <td style="width: 10%; text-align: left;">Sheet No</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;"></td>

                <td style="width: 10%; text-align: left;">Rev. No.</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;">Item Description</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;" colspan="2"></td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;">ITP Stage Nos.</td>
                <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;" colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Fitup data table-sm  -->
        <table class="table  table-bordered table-condensed">

            <tr>
                <th rowspan="12" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <span class="verticaltext"> Fabrication Assembly Fit-Up </span>
                </th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Weld/joint
                    No</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Item/Position
                    No.</th>
                <th colspan="2">Material Spec Grade</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Size</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Thickness</th>
                <th colspan="2">Heat/Plate/TestNo</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Welder
                    No. for tracking</th>
                <th colspan="2">Fitup Result</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Date</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="2">Sign</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <th>Material 1</th>
                <th>Material 2</th>

                <th>Material 1</th>
                <th>Material 2</th>

                <th>Accept</th>
                <th>Reject</th>

            </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
        
                    <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                        
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Name & Signature of fabrication foreman</td>
                <td colspan="2">Released to</td>

                <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox"> QC/NDE/DIM.</td>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox"> Welding</td>

                <td colspan="4"><input type="checkbox">
                    Fabrication/Assembly</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">Date</td>
                <td colspan="7">Date</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- welding data -->
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="13" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
                    <span class="verticaltext"> Welding Details </span>
                </th>

                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3">Joint
                    No</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3">WPS
                    No.</th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Welding Process</th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Welder/Operation No.</th>
                <th colspan="2" rowspan="2" class="text-center">Visual
                    Inspection</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3">Date</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;" rowspan="3">Sign</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Passes</th>
                <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Passes</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Root/Hot</th>
                <th class="text-center">Fill</th>
                <th class="text-center">Cap</th>

                <th class="text-center">Root/Hot</th>
                <th class="text-center">Fill</th>
                <th class="text-center">Cap</th>

                <th class="text-center">Accept</th>
                <th class="text-center">Reject</th>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>

            <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Name & Signature of fabrication foreman</td>
                <td colspan="3">Released to</td>

                <td colspan="2"><input type="checkbox"> QC/NDE/DIM.</td>
                <td colspan="1"><input type="checkbox"> Welding</td>

                <td colspan="4"><input type="checkbox">
                    Fabrication/Assembly</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="14">Name & Signature of QC Personel</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">Date</td>
                <td colspan="7">Date</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are 10 rows in each table, due to stack overflow limitations I short the code. Can any one help me with this Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I did try with 10 rows in the two tables and this configuration seems to have worked out for me.

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    @media print {
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        table:nth-of-type(2) {
            margin-top:-90px;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        @page {
            size: A4 landscape;
            margin: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

**table:nth-of-type(2)** is used to specifically work on the **2nd table**, in your case the **Fabrication Assembly Fit-Up Table**.
Hope this helped.

Comment: Stil it splits into two pages bro. I am using opera, is this a reason?

Comment: I tried in chrome. Works fine for me. If yoiu want I can somehow send you a downloaded copy of the pdf with one A4 page in output, according to this CSS setup. Check out if that does the trick, or else go a different route. If you have chrome installed, might want to try on that, once.

Comment: can you send me a copy of pdf. I tried in edge too, it is breaking. The chrome is not working in my pc it shows something went wrong page

Comment: How do you want me to send it? Email, maybe?

Comment: by email ajb.devp@gmail.com

Comment: Was this the output that you were looking for? By the way, I use Chrome 85.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220693/discussion-between-alvin-john-niravukalayil-and-adil-ahmed).